# How to write gz file in C via zlib and compress2

Tags: c, io, compression, zlib

I'm using zlib to write a program that compress data in several threads. so I can't use gzwrite. I'm using compress2().

```
*dest_len = compressBound(LOG_BUFF_SZ);
err = compress2((Bytef*)compressed_buff->buff, dest_len, (Bytef*)b->buff, size, GZ_INT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL);
write(fd, compressed_buff->buff, compressed_buff->full);
```

But when I try to decompress file via gzip -d  I see the next output: "not in gzip format". what am I doing wrong? Thank you for your answers

Comment: Are you compressing _one_ file in different threads?

Comment: @AnishRam, actually I compress not file, but incoming buffer. It's something like logging system. And yes, I compress it in differrent threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`compress()` and `compress2()` compress to the [zlib format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950), not the [gzip format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).  You need to use the lower-level functions to be able to select the gzip format.  Those are `deflateInit2()`, `deflate()` and `deflateEnd()`.  Read the documentation in [zlib.h](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) for those functions.  After that, you should also look at the [heavily documented example of their use](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html).